# Running Angular app as docker image using Node js

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Trying to build angular application in docker and run as container in my local using Node js.

I have used build image using below Dockerfile, but i am not sure what i am missing while running. Can someone point me out?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.3
ENV HOME=/home
WORKDIR $HOME
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false \
    && npm config set proxy http://proxy.xxxxxx.com:8080
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
```

Image created with below command successfully

```
docker build -t example .
```

I am trying to run the image using below command, but it is not helping

```
docker run -p 4201:4200 example
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? your build image will just install dependencies for your angular app.

Comment: I don't see docker container running after executing docker run command as above. I have verified using docker ps.

Comment: If I were you, I would add details about if this is for a production or development use case. You might get different answer based on this. Basically the `ng` cli is not suitable to serve apps in production. You should use a proper server like nginx or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your Dockerfile does not run/serve your application, in order to do that you have to:

- install angular/cli
- copy the app
- run/serve the app

```
FROM node:10.15.3

RUN npm config set strict-ssl false \
    && npm config set proxy http://proxy.xxxxxx.com:8080

# get the app
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

# install packages
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

# start app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

hope this helps.

Comment: JFYI, It's not a best practice to run an angular app on the production environment using `ng serve`.

Comment: For Complete Docker beginners, this post might be helpful to understand if you want to run Angular inside Docker https://thecodeframework.com/run-angular-app-inside-a-docker-container-in-5-mins/

Answer (score 2):

Container need a foreground process running, then it will not exit. If not, the container will directly exit.

For your case, you need to `COPY` your nodejs project to container when `docker build`, and also start the project in `CMD` like `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]`. As the web server not exit, then your container will not exit.

A good article [here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) for your reference on how to dockerizing a Node.js web app.

Comment: The article was very good to know some base point about each step.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your Dockerfile to achieve your goal for more options see [here](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-an-angular-app/):

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0

RUN npm config set strict-ssl false \
    && npm config set proxy http://proxy.xxxxxx.com:8080

# install chrome for protractor tests
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9

# add app
COPY . /app

# start app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot for the following Dockerfile as well!

```
FROM node:alpine

# get the app
WORKDIR /src

# install packages
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# start app
CMD ["ng", "serve", "-o"]
```